# I get an error when using django-graphene

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, graphql

I am trying to create a graphql schema with graphene-django.
I am using python3.5 and graphene==1.4.1 and graphene-django==1.3

This is my module:

```
class category(models.Model):
    QUESTION = 'Q'
    SOLUTION = 'S'
    UNKNOWN = 'U'
    CATEGORY_CHOICE = (
        ('quiz', (
            (QUESTION, 'Question'),
            (SOLUTION, 'Solution'),
        )
         ),
        (UNKNOWN, 'Unknown'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/category/', default='anonymous.jpg')
```

And this is my schema:

```
class Query(graphene.AbstractType):
    category = graphene.Field(categoryType, id=graphene.Int())
    def resolve_category(self, info, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.get('id')
        if id is not None:
            return models.category.objects.get(pk=id)
        return None
```

and:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType, schema.Query):
    pass


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

with this query:

```
query{
  category(id: 1){
    id
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "message": "resolve_category() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "category": null
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help.
By the way, I have used this tutorial:
http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/#getting-single-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is referencing the 2.0 version of graphene, which got rid of some of those arguments. The major version of the django package was bumped as well. Upgrade both with:

```
pip install "graphene>=2.0.dev"
pip install "graphene-django>=2.0.dev"
```